# Older home, how to tell if circuit has a GFCI, when the walls are covered

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, garbage-disposal

I am replacing a Food disposal/dispenser and newer model has a plug (not hard wired). As a result and a *precaution* I am `installing a GFCI outlet for the Garbage Disposal`, (*I do know how to look for GFCI outlets and GFCI Circuit breakers*).

So my question/issue, is **how can I tell if a circuit has a GFCI wired somewhere in the circuit**; *since the walls are covered* and `I don't know which outlets that wire feeding the dispenser touches`.

Comment: A GFCI device would not be buried in a wall.  It's either part of your breaker, or in an receptacle downstream in the circuit.  Since the disposal should be on a dedicated circuit, the latter is unlikely.

Comment: Get a GFCI tester.

Answer (score 2):

The disposal should be on a dedicated circuit. But for a variety of reasons it might not be. But with a standard receptacle (as opposed to hard-wired), you can use a [GFCI tester](https://amzn.to/3i1x2h4):

[image: Klein RT210]

and see if it activates a GFCI somewhere (a receptacle or breaker, though you had better know which breaker this circuit is on before you start doing any of this work). Note that if there is no ground connected then a GFCI tester such as this one will **not** work, though you should then see "Open Ground". (If ground is connected directly to neutral then GFCI won't work *and* it will show "Correct", but that is a different sort of mess, which you hopefully don't have.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to look for GFCI outlets and breakers, trip everyone you find, then check the outlet in question, the disposal/dispenser, and see if it still has power. If it does, it's not on any of the GFCI circuits and you can add one.

Answer (score 0):

Your disposal should be on a dedicated circuit.

If not due to wrong wiring, get a tracer tool and find out what outlets start chirping. 50 bucks at the big orange box store or at you owes them.